# How to boot a USB to reinstall windows when I have ubuntu installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, usb

My ubuntu system is basically useless now because it always says the error "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /". I can't do anything with it because of that. :( and I want to go back to windows 7 for now and I am on Ubuntu and it's the only OS that is in my computer, but it seems that when I go to the boot options when I restart my PC, it could not detect the bootable USB that I have, and I read somewhere that Ubuntu couldn't detect the bootable USB in the bootloader, so can someone help me boot my USB to reinstall windows 7?

Thank you :)

PS. I have another laptop that I used to check if it is read as bootable, and it is able to detect it. In my ubuntu laptop, it just says USB HDD on the boot menu, but when I run it on a different laptop that currently runs on windows 7 it is named that it is an installation for win 7. Which means my windows 7 laptop can boot a USB but my ubuntu laptop can't.

Comment: Booting from USB has nothing to do with the OS installed on the internal disk. Check your BIOS settings.

Comment: Which specific settings should I look at? I tried it before, my ubuntu laptop only says USB HDD, but when I did it on my windows laptop, it has a different name and I was able to test it there.

Comment: That's hard to say, check all settings ragarding USB support, especially disabled things. You probably also have to change the order of devices to boot from. Here are some tips: http://lifehacker.com/5991848/how-to-boot-from-a-cd-or-usb-drive-on-any-pc

Comment: I can't really do anything on my ubuntu system because of the error stated above, do you have any suggestions on how to fix it? And also it's always on read only memory, I guess that's why I can't do anything on it.

Comment: As I said above, you must check the **BIOS** settings, you want to boot from the USB disk, this happens before you start the installed OS. Look at the link I provided.

Comment: SLR, but thanks for replying to everything. Will go back here after attempting it.

Comment: I finally got it working! I was successful in booting it via legacy instead of UEFI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my 2 laptops (samsung and msi).

Both laptops randomly don't detect bootable USB flash drives. So, to make it works, I tried to **power off and on** (not just reboot) my laptop 3-5 times and finally bootable USB get detected. Another trick which sometimes works for me - turn on laptop by pressing the power button, **then wait about 1 second** and only then connect USB drive.

It might be also good to see is USB detected by bios or not. If you enter in your bios settings when laptop starts and see list of devices on first screen, you might see your HDD and USB drive if it gets detected well. Usually USB drive detected with name and size
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w08qm.jpg)

Another option to try - read messages in your laptop when it starts. Many laptops has quick boot menu option. So, you might read message about that mode. On my laptop it called "Press F2 for Boot Menu". You can try to found that key for your laptop model [in that table](https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so normally when a computer boots, it does this:

1) FIRST it loads the BIOS.

2) SECOND it loads an operating system from the HARD-DRIVE.

---

Different computer manufacturers have different settings in the bios by default, which you can change.

So to change the boot-order on your first laptop you can try the following:

---

A) CHANGE BIOS BOOT ORDER!

Go into your BIOS settings, and tell the BIOS to FIRST check for a bootable USB-flash-drive, BEFORE it loads the operating system on the hard-drive.

How do you get into your bios? Well, when your first turn on your computer, you will have to press a key at start up. For example, with my computer, I can press either "F2" or the "DEL" (delete) key when I turn on the power, and that will take me into the BIOS.

When I turn on the power, I simply just keep pressing that key over and over, until it "catches" and I enter the BIOS.

Confusingly, different computers have different "BIOS" access keys. For some you have to press "ESC"... others you press "DEL", or "F2" or "F12" or "ENTER", etc...  Usually the computer will flash a quick-start-up screen, and that screen tells you which key to press.

The problem is that screen sometimes flashes by too fast, for you to read it!

If that's the case, you can just film the screen at start-up with your smart phone, and then play back the video on your phone, and pause it, so you can read what's on the screen.

Another way to find out is to try googling the model/brand of your computer followed by the words "BIOS key", and you should get your answer there as well.

Once you get inside the BIOS you have to search around all the menus, and play with the right settings to change the boot-order. (All the BIOS' are different, and some are very confusing... but if you spend a bit of time in there, you'll find the right settings.)

---

NOTE:

Getting into the bios, to change settings, usually has NOTHING to do with the operating system (Ubuntu or otherwise). So the fact that your hard-drive has Ubuntu installed should be IRRELEVANT. What is relevant is simply the key you press (to access the BIOS) when you first turn on your computer BEFORE the operating system loads.

ALSO NOTE:

The reason your second laptop is able to boot the USB, might simply be because it has a different default boot-order (in that it first checks for a bootable USB, and then if it doesn't find one, it then checks the hard-drive). If somebody else installed Windows on your 2nd lap-top, for you in the past, then that person might have been the one to change the boot-order! (Or maybe the manufacturer set the boot-order in that way...)

---

B) UEFI BIOS

So yes, with most computers Method A above will work, and allow you to change the boot order.

BUT... very ANNOYINGLY some of the newer computers (particularly those with UEFI bios) LOCK themselves to a single operating system. This is often called "SECURE BOOT".

So no matter if you go into the BIOS, and simply change the boot order or not, it will ONLY boot into the operating system that it is "locked onto".

Thus with the UEFI bios, you often have to take some extra steps, and hunt around the settings in the BIOS menu, looking for other options to "turn off "SECURE BOOT", and/or change the default boot operating system, and then finally... change the boot order.

So in other words, if you have a newer UEFI BIOS that is "locked" to a particular OS, you have to go into the BIOS, turn off secure-boot, and then perhaps change the name of the operating system it is pointing to, and then finally also change the boot order.

Either way, to boot from your USB, the key is to go into the BIOS and change settings there.

---

AFTER ALL THIS... if you try everything and are unable to do it, you might be able to pay a local consultant or tech support person in your area (or even take your machine to Geek-Squad at Best-Buy) for them to have a quick look at, and simply show you how to change the boot order on that particular model.

They should NOT charge you very much money, just to simply teach you to change boot order... so it shouldn't be expensive. Once they show you how to do that, then you can just simply install the Windows-7-OS yourself, as you are planning to do.

Answer (score 0):

first, create a bootable disk using  unetbootin 
https://unetbootin.github.io/
Check the boot order on bios you may need to select usb drive unless you able to change the boot order (Dell laptops usually F12 etc)
If you create a live USB you will be able to boot from the Live ubuntu from the USB